# How to handle exception when using ThreadedWebsocketManager from python-binance?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, binance

is there a way that i can handle ThreadedWebsocketManager exceptions, the current behavior is that i see the exceptions on the black screen but am not able to enter the except part even if i wrap it with try except.

```
from binance import Client, ThreadedWebsocketManager
bm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)
bm.start()
bm.start_kline_socket(callback=handle_socket_message, symbol=symbol, interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE)
```